# PySpark and Kafka with SSL

Tags: apache-spark, ssl, apache-kafka

What is the correct syntax in Python (pyspark) to connect to Kafka cluster with SSL?

I have a local kafka cluster (for testing purpose) with included SSL.
I was able to connect Scala with local cluster but not PySpark yet..

So far I have:

```
kafkaBrokers = "localhost:9093"
schemaRegistryUrl = "https://registry:8081/"
inputTopic = "test.spark"
df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers).option("schema.registry", schemaRegistryUrl).option("subscribe", inputTopic).load()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "kafka-spark.py", line 31, in <module>
    df = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers).option("schema.registry", schemaRegistryUrl).option("subscribe", inputTopic).load()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/streaming.py", line 403, in load
    return self._df(self._jreader.load())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/2.3.0/libexec/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o30.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: kafka. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:635)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.DataStreamReader.load(DataStreamReader.scala:159)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23$$anonfun$apply$15.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$23.apply(DataSource.scala:618)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:618)
    ... 12 more
```

Comment: It fails because it _Failed to find data source: kafka._. You probablly didn't include `spark-sql-kafka` package.

Comment: How do you include it with Python (pyspark)?

Comment: For example with `--pakcages` option to `spark-submit` or `spark.jars.packages` in the Spark defaults configuration.

Comment: Thanks. Passed that error.. Now is a new one.. ` found org.scalactic#scalactic_2.11;3.0.1 in local-m2-cache
 found org.scala-lang#scala-reflect;2.11.8 in spark-list` -> It just hangs and no error, but no connection either...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below stack overflow link to handle SSL in structured streaming

[Failed to find leader for topics; java.lang.NullPointerException NullPointerException at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.formatAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755063/failed-to-find-leader-for-topics-java-lang-nullpointerexception-nullpointerexce/58860695#58860695)