# How to connect to a kerberos-secured kafka cluster running on gcp using pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-kafka, kerberos, sasl

So before I start i want to say that I know that this question might seem repeated or duplicated but the answers which are available out there are not related to my requirements. They are mostly for java and scala but only a little about python.

So i have a kerberos-secured kafka cluster running on gcp. And i checked twice that is running by creating producer and consumer using kafka-python package and it is working perfectly.

But when i try to connect to that cluster with my spark application using pyspark it doesnt work. My spark application looks like this:-

```
def application(topic, batchTime, appName, **kwargs):
    import os

    try:
        os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars <full-path-to-spark>/jars/spark-streaming-kafka-0-8-assembly_2.11-2.4.4.jar pyspark-shell'

        conf = SparkConf().setAppName(appName).setMaster('local[*]') 
        sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

        stream_context = StreamingContext(sparkContext=sc, batchDuration=batchTime)
        kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc=stream_context, topics=[topic], 
                                            kafkaParams={"metadata.broker.list":"broker1:9092",
                                                    "ssl.context": 'context',
                                                    'sasl.plain.username': '****',
                                                    'sasl.plain.password': '*********',
                                                    'sasl.mechanism': 'PLAIN',
                                                    'security.protocol': "SASL_PLAINTEXT"})

        lines = kafka_stream.map(lambda x: json.loads(x[1]))
        final_obj = lines.map(lambda line: SparkHelper.get_app_type(line, line['app_type']))
        final_obj.foreachRDD(handler)

        final_obj.pprint()
```

when i run this it shows error like:-

```
19/11/26 19:11:59 WARN Utils: Your hostname, openstack-inspiron-3543 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.1.1; using 10.10.0.25 instead (on interface wlp6s0)
19/11/26 19:11:59 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
19/11/26 19:11:59 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/11/26 19:12:01 WARN Utils: Service 'SparkUI' could not bind on port 4040. Attempting port 4041.
19/11/26 19:12:01 WARN VerifiableProperties: Property sasl.mechanism is not valid
19/11/26 19:12:01 WARN VerifiableProperties: Property sasl.plain.password is not valid
19/11/26 19:12:01 WARN VerifiableProperties: Property sasl.plain.username is not valid
19/11/26 19:12:01 WARN VerifiableProperties: Property security.protocol is not valid
19/11/26 19:12:01 WARN VerifiableProperties: Property ssl.context is not valid
```

And the console stucks there. It doesnt terminate nor runs anything. And yeah this happen only when my local kafka cluster is running. If i close it and run the spark application it shows "NoBrokerAvailable". This shouldnt happen right? Doesnt matter if my local kafka cluster is running or not when i am trying to connect to the different cluster all together.

I tried installing a different spark-stream-kafka-assembly jar file but none of them works. I downloaded the jar file from https://jar-download.com/?search_box=spark-streaming-kafka-assembly.

Current versions i am using are...

Spark: 2.4.4,
Hadoop:  2.7,
api_version: 0.10

I am using confluent platform 5.3.1 to run a kafka cluster.

I dont understand where the problem is. Please point out any mistakes that i am making or if there isnt what should i change to make this work. Thanks for your response in advance!!

Comment: Pyspark still uses the internal Java/Scala kafka and Spark libraries, so any answer for those should translate to pyspark, such as you should be providing a keytab to the Spark submit command

Comment: Yeah, I tried a few of those solutions. Like adding the prefix "Kafka" for every Kafka-params. But it doesn't work. I also dont know how to provide a keytab. @cricket_007

Comment: When running `spark-submit` , you can add `-–conf spark.yarn.keytab=path_to_keytab -–conf spark.yarn.principal=principal@REALM.COM` or you can add these properties to the SparkConf object

Comment: I dont have a keytab file at the cluster. Kerberos is just authenticating username and password that kafkaclient is sending. There is only jaas file at the cluster side.

Comment: If the job is long-running, then you will need a keytab for re-authorization because Kerberos requires it. As mentioned in the Spark docs - https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#long-running-applications (this assumes your Hadoop cluster also uses Kerberos)

Comment: Okay but this thing i have to worry about after its connected with kafka cluster. But its not connecting to that cluster. And that cluster is sasl protected. I am specifically looking for that. @cricket_007

Answer (score 0):

Instead of DSstream method you can try Pyspark structured streaming as that has the options to pass the SSL features and easily process as well. Please refer tested sample code in below stack overflow link . 
[Failed to find leader for topics; java.lang.NullPointerException NullPointerException at org.apache.kafka.common.utils.Utils.formatAddress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58755063/failed-to-find-leader-for-topics-java-lang-nullpointerexception-nullpointerexce/58860695#58860695)

Comment: Yeah i tried that and its working but then not able to perform sql operations. It throws error everytime i try that

Comment: Can you please share what SQL operation you are performing and what error you are facing .

Comment: should i post a new question for that or just edit this question?

Comment: may be you can post new question if stack overflow policy allows you !! Thanks

Comment: sure i will post a new question